# Lexical Analysis of a Scripting Language

Tags: parsing, scripting, analysis, analyzer, lexical

I am trying to create a simple script for a resource API. I have a resource API mainly creates game resources in a structured manner. What I want is dealing with this API without creating c++ programs each time I want a resource. So we (me and my instructor from uni) decided to create a simple script to create/edit resource files without compiling every time. There are also some other irrelevant factors that I need a command line interface rather than a GUI program.

Anyway, here is script sample:

```
<path>.<command> -<options>
/Graphics[3].add "blabla.png"
```

I didn't design this script language, the owner of API did. The part before '.' as you can guess is the path and part after '.' is actual command and some options, flags etc. As a first step, I tried to create grammar of left part because I thought I could use it while searching info about lexical analyzers and parser. The problem is I am inexperienced when it comes to parsing and programming languages and I am not sure if it's correct or not. Here is some more examples and grammar of left side.

```
dir -> '/' | '/' path
path -> object '/' path | object
object -> number | string '[' number ']'
```

Notation if this grammar can be a mess, I don't know. There is 5 different possibilities, they are:

```
String
"String"
Number
String[Number]
"String"[Number]
```

It has to start with '/' symbol and if it's the only symbol, I will accept it as Root.

Now my problem is how can I lexically analyze this script? Is there a special method? What should my lexical analyzer do and do not(I read some lexical analysers also do syntactic analysis up to a point). Do you think grammar, etc. is technically appropriate? What kind of parsing method I should use(Recursive Descent, LL etc.)? I am trying to make it technically appropriate piece of work. It's not commercial so I have time thus I can learn lexical analysis and parsing better. I don't want to use a parser library.

Comment: If you didn't design the [DSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language), why are you writing a parser for it? If it's an existing DSL isn't there an existing parser implementation?

Comment: Why use this weird custom scripting language at all? Binding a more standard language to the API should be easier and better for everyone involved.

Comment: It is not a commercial project and decisions are made by my instructor. It's both for me to gain experience on parsers and lexical analyzers and decreasing the time req. for resource creation process. It is not an existing DSL but I have to write lexer and parser.

Comment: Have you looked at using a parser generator? Wikipedia has a nice [comparison of parser generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators) you can look at. Also, from what you've described so far this looks like a *regular language*. Do you have a full grammar yet?

Comment: Yes I did but I don't want to use them. They are my last option if I fail to create parser. My main aim is gaining some parser experience rather than getting the work done. Right side is not completely decided and it will follow linux commands more closely but it's not fully decided. I need to finish left side first. It's grammar is written. Not completely sure if it's appropriate or not.

Comment: Actually, I think learning to use one of those parser generators is going to be harder than writing a parser for your simple language!

Comment: @DaoWen: that's quite possibly true, but learning to use a parser generator is a really good learning exercise, and will provide many rewards later on.

Comment: @rici: I totally agree. The learning curve might be a bit steeper, but coding up your grammar with a standard tool usually makes it much more readable and easier to maintain than a hand-coded grammar, and for most applications using DSLs any performance difference will be negligible since the inputs are so small.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **What should my lexical analyzer do and not do?**

It should:

- recognize tokens
- ignore ignorable whitespace and comments (if there are such things)
- optionally, keep track of source location in order to produce meaningful error messages.

It should not attempt to parse the input, although that will be very tempting with such a simple language.

From what I can see, you have the following tokens:

- punctuation: `/`, `.`, linear-white-space, new-line
- numbers
- unquoted strings (often called "atoms" or "ids")
- quoted strings (possibly the same token type as unquoted strings)

I'm not sure what the syntax for `-options` is, but that might include more possibilities.

Choosing to return `linear-white-space` (that is, a  sequence consisting only of tabs and spaces) as a token is somewhat questionable; it complicates the grammar considerably, particularly since there are probably places where white-space is ignorable, such as the beginning and end of a line. But I have the intuition that you do not want to allow whitespace inside of a path and that you plan to require it between the command name and its arguments. That is, you want to prohibit:

```
/left /right[3] .whimper "hello, world"
/left/right[3].whimper"hello, world"
```

But maybe I'm wrong. Maybe you're happy to accept both. That would be simpler, because if you accept both, then you can just ignore linear-whitespace altogether.

By the way, experience has shown that using new-line to separate commands can be awkward; sooner or later you will need to break a command into two lines in order to avoid having to buy an extra monitor to see the entire line. The convention (used by bash and the C preprocessor, amongst others) of putting a `\` as the last character on a line to be continued is possible, but can lead to annoying bugs (like having an invisible space following the `\` and thus preventing it from really continuing the line).

---

From here down is 100% personal opinion, offered for free. So take it for what its worth.

**I am trying to make it technically appropriate piece of work. It's not commercial so I have time thus I can learn lexical analysis and parsing better. I don't want to use a parser library.**

There is a contradiction here, in my opinion. Or perhaps two contradictions.

A technically appropriate piece of work would use standard tools; at least a lexical generator and probably a parser generator. It would do that because, properly used, the lexical and grammatical descriptions provided to the tools document precisely the actual language, and the tools guarantee that the desired language is what is actually recognized. Writing ad hoc code, even simple lexical recognizers and recursive descent parsers, for all that it can be elegant, is less self-documenting, less maintainable, and provides fewer guarantees of correctness. Consequently, best practice is "use standard tools".

Secondly, I disagree with your instructor (if I understand their proposal correctly, based on your comments) that writing ad hoc lexers and parsers aids in understanding lexical and parsing theory. In fact, it may be counterproductive. Bottom-up parsing, which is incredibly elegant both theoretically and practically, is almost impossible to write by hand and totally impossible to read. Consequently, many programmers prefer to use recursive-descent or Pratt parsers, because they understand the code. However, such parsers are not as powerful as a bottom-up parser (particularly GLR or Earley parsers, which are fully general), and their use leads to unnecessary grammatical compromises.

You don't need to write a regular expression library to understand regular expressions. The libraries abstract away the awkward implementation details (and there are lots of them, and they really are awkward) and let you concentrate on the essence of creating and using regular expressions.

In the same way, you do not need to write a compiler in order to understand how to program in C. *After* you have a good basis in C, you can improve your understanding (maybe) by understanding how it translates into machine code, but unless you plan a career in compiler writing, knowing the details of obscure optimization algorithms are not going to make you a better programmer. Or, at least, they're not first on your agenda.

Similarly, once you really understand regular expressions, you might find writing a library interesting. Or not -- you might find it incredibly frustrating and give up after a couple of months of hard work. Either way, you will appreciate existing libraries more. But learn to use the existing libraries first.

And the same with parser generators. If you want to learn how to translate an idea for a programming language into something precise and implementable, learn how to use a parser generator. Only after you have mastered the theory of parsing should you even think of focusing on low-level implementations.

Comment: I think that the _ids_ and _strings_ are actually the same type here, where quotes are only needed if you have special characters (spaces?) in the _id_. Given that's true, he should really generate the same token type in both cases.

Comment: @DaoWen: probably true, but it's not clear that they are the same token type in command arguments. As OP develops his grammar, these things should become clearer.

Comment: @DaoWen, you are right. Quotation Marks are only needed for whitespaces.

Comment: @cengizkandemir: surely also for `/`, `.` and maybe for leading digits?